# Get size of struct in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check the number of bytes consumed by my Structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361986/how-to-check-the-number-of-bytes-consumed-by-my-structure)

I have a struct in the packed form of

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct test
{
  public int a;
  public uint16 b;
}
```

How do I get the size of the struct as the compiler states that sizeof can only be used in unsafe context?

Comment: I need to send it over the network. I got the API which need me to specify the bytes of the struct including the header + data etc

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418749/c-why-sizeof-is-unsafe-and-how-to-get-size-of-a-struct-in-a-safe-way

Comment: How about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof.aspx ? Make sure you read the information in the sub pages.

Comment: There are plenty of other questions covering this already. Did you search before posting?

Comment: Marshal.SizeOf<T>()

Answer (score 69):

The [`SizeOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s4920fa.aspx) method does the trick.

```
int size = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Point));
```

Comment: To be more specific, it's System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf, applied to an instance. Should return the same results as the language "sizeof" applied to the type. Example below.

Comment: This worked in combination with Reb.Cabin's comment. Thanks, now i can actually find out whats an efficient structure and whats not.

Comment: typeof(Point), Point is a class. With struct it gives me Exception!! Try int size = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(test));

Comment: I don't think that's the size of the struct. It's the size the struct gets marshalled to.

Answer (score 6):

You put the sizeof operator into an unsafe context just like the compiler suggests?

Something like this I guess:

```
int size;
unsafe
{
    size=sizeof(Test);
}
```

But I'm not sure if you really want to do that. I'd tend to use a normal serializer instead of structs with specific layout for this. IMO you should use such structs only for native interop and not for simple serialization.

And looking at the documentation of the `SizeOf` function marshalling can mess with the size too(not in this example though).

Comment: That would still give the compilation error.

Comment: @JohnB.Lambe What do you mean? This code compiles and returns `6`, as expected (once you fix the trivial mistakes in the OP's code)

Comment: @Porges `unsafe` is not contagious. You just need use the proper flag for the assembly and mark the relevant code block `unsafe`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: yes, this comment is incorrect. It feels like that's how `unsafe` *should* work, though :)

Comment: Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type :(