# C# structure size evaluation

Tags: c#, struct, offset

Please, can anyone tell what is the size of the structure, and how to calculate it:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=2)]
public struct SomeStruct
{
     public short sh;
     public int   i;
     public byte  b;
     public ushort u;
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=7)]
     public byte[] arr;
}
```

Comment: Should be 118 bytes. To be sure, the easist way is to make a small console program with Console.WriteLine(sizeof(SomeStruct)).

Comment: Of course, that struct is misaligned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want to understand how is memory allocated, otherwise you can use:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(TheStruct)
```

Well you choose to pack in a 2 byte boundary, so you basically allocate memory at step of two.
so `short` ( signed or unsigned ) take 2 bytes, `int` take four bytes `byte` would take just one, but due to the packing you specify take two as well, for the same reason  for the array we need to consider 8.
So we have

```
2+4+2+2+8 = 18 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get exact size of this structure using following code -

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(SomeStruct)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int size = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(new SomeStruct());
Console.WriteLine(size);
```

or, from a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956435/get-size-of-struct-in-c-sharp), this:

```
int size;
unsafe
{
    size = sizeof(SomeStruct);
}
```

Both will yield 18, as Felice Pollano has explained.